# How to restore expired domain?

Tags: yahoo, domain

I already sent 3 emails to SmallBusiness Yahoo Help division, but none got a reply (even though they say that, they answer in 24 hours).

I have used their [Email Us](http://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/contactus/email_us.php) form.

Bottom line is that I have a client (where her domain registar is Yahoo) that told me that was ok to let her domain to expire, now, she changed her mind.

Where do I click and pay to **re-active the domain**? 
There is no such options on the control panel and when I try to access the domain options I always get an error page.

Does anyone know how/where should I look/go as I can't do anything with Yahoo? 
And their [Let Us Call You](http://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/contactus/schedule_cb.php?q=Domains_Tech) does not support a Danish number :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got an email from Yahoo, and I just want to share the process:

1. Visit the link: https://order.smallbusiness.yahoo.com/order/reactivatedomain
2. Type in your domain name and click "Reactivate this Account".
3. Sign in using the Yahoo! ID and password.
4. Choose the desired options and click  Continue  through the steps that follow. Fill out your payment information.
5. Review your order, and click the "Place Order" button.

*So easy... and then, so hard to answer :/*